# Google Sheets: using index() to automatically populate the formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have this sheet:

[image]

I sum the value of A, B, C and put the result in column F. I use simple formula :

```
=A1+B1+C1
```

But rather than doing the copy/paste the formula to F2 - F5, I modify the formula using index() to populate the formula:

```
=index(A1:A5+B1:B5+C1:C5)
```

This will automatically calculate all the 5 rows. But now i want to use sum():

```
=sum(A1:C1)
```

Does anyone know how to use index() like the previous formula to automatically count for each of row?

Thanks,
Andi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUM` is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA` / `INDEX` so you need to use `MMULT`:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(A1:C3, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A:C))^0))
```

[image]

Comment: It works great, the only limitation with MMULT the value in the range (col A to C) can't be empty otherwise i got error. So it won't be automatically treated as 0.

Comment: @andio you can do `A1:C3*1`

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand your question. But, you can enter an array formula once and it will automatically fill in formulas below. So change this:

```
=sum(A1:C1)
```

to this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A + B1:B + C1:C)
```

Comment: Thanks , yes something like that , but i want to use sum() rather than '+' , because in case there's lot of column to sum then have to type very long formula. For example : A1:A+B1:B+...XA1:XA